# Golang jwt.StandardClaims time format type issue

Tags: go, jwt, claims-authentication

I am using this package `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4` to set up claims in a Login function:

```
now := time.Now()
claims := &jwt.StandardClaims{
    Issuer: "Test",
    ExpiresAt: now.Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix(),
}
```

The IDE keeps telling me:

> Cannot use 'now.Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()' (type int64) as the type *Time*.

I read that as I have the wrong typed value, however, on all the examples I've seen online, this is exactly how the majority set up this up.

I am still learning go and so I am not sure the proper way to convert this time format into something that is valid.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `.Unix()` part.

Comment: I've tried that. It then gives the same error but says Cannot use type Time as the type *Time.

Comment: it works if you dont use v4. Looks like v4 introduced breaking changes. It is also a preview version. So no offical docs are there yet.

Comment: That was the issue. I'm using v3.2 and all is well.

Comment: don't use `github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go`, it has critical security issues

Answer (score 9):

In github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4 StandardClaims type is deprecated, you should replace StandardClaims with RegisteredClaims.

And about `Cannot use 'now.Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()' (type int64) as the type Time.` you need to use NumericDate type, so your code will looks like this:

```
claims := &jwt.RegisteredClaims{
    Issuer: "Test",
    ExpiresAt: &jwt.NumericDate{now.Add(time.Hour * 24)},
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, you can change

```
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4 => github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4   //v4.4.3

StandardClaims => RegisteredClaims

now.Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()  => jwt.NewNumericDate(now.Add(time.Hour * 24))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
func GenerateToken(username, password string) (string, error) {
    nowTime := time.Now()
    expireTime := nowTime.Add(12 * time.Hour)

    claims := Claims{
        username,
        password,
        jwt.RegisteredClaims{
            ExpiresAt: jwt.NewNumericDate(expireTime),
            Issuer:    "test",
        },
    }
    
    tokenClaims := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claims)
    token, err := tokenClaims.SignedString(jwtSecret)

    return token, err
}
```

You can try it

Answer (score 0):

`ExpiresAt` requires the datatype to be `*time.Time` and the function `Unix()` returns the time in a number of seconds in `int64`.

I recommend you to use the package [`github.com/golang-jwt/jwt`](https://github.com/golang-jwt/jwt) rather than the one you are using now, which is no longer maintained.

Answer (score -1):

your code is Okay the problem is with the importation of your package you can change the import

from

```
"github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4"
```

to

```
"github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
```